# how to label scalars in slqalchemy select list

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm wondering how to write the equivalent of this with sqlalchemy

```
SELECT 'foo' as "bar", company.name FROM company;
```

I'd like to write it like;

```
session.query(some_function('foo').label('bar'), Company.name)
```

where some_function is the identity. One work around is something like

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(func.cast('foo', String).label('bar'), Company.name)
```

but it doesn't work in cases where you might want foo to be an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`literal`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal) function:

```
session.query(literal('foo').label('bar'), Company.name)
```